# Finding Passenger Lists for Irish immigrants to USA 1923-1925?

Tags: manifest, ireland, california

I'm trying to locate the following family on the passenger lists.

- Richard Richardson born c1897
- Mary/Molly Richardson born  c1895
- Jane Richardson born c1923

All born in Co. Cork, Ireland.

They would have left Ireland c1923 and they appear in the US censuses 1930 & 1940. They lived in San Francisco, CA.

I know all about them here in Ireland but would love to see all the details on the passenger list.

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy and Family History SE! I've edited your question to improve readability. I've also removed your tagline per the [FAQ](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures). Because your post are always pre-signed, no use re-signing them. Feel free to edit back if I've changed to much. Again, welcome to GFH.SE!

Comment: Richard and Mary were my grandparents, and Jane was my Aunt. Was there specific information you were looking for? Richard did arrive in the U.S. via Canada so that is likely the proper record.

Answer (score 6):

I found the [arrival records](http://search.ancestry.com/browse/view.aspx?dbid=7488&iid=NYT715_3718-0571&pid=2001440880&ssrc=&fn=Jane+M&ln=Richardson&st=g) of Mary and Jane; Richard appears to have come over earlier. You'll need an Ancestry.com account to get at this manifest, or you can try to find it on [Ellis Island](http://ellisisland.org) site. The name of the ship is Carmania. It sailed from Cobh, Ireland to New York, arriving on 13 Sep 1925. These two are on page 19 of 92. Don't forget that these manifest pages are split into two images; hit the 'next page' link to see the second page that shows they were coming to join husband/father Richard Richardson who was then living at 1740 Church St., in San Francisco.

With respect to Richard's arrival, there is a [single record](http://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?gl=40&rank=1&new=1&so=3&MSAV=1&msT=1&gss=ms_r_f-40&gsfn=richard&gsfn_x=XO&gsln=richardson&gsln_x=XO&msbdy=1897&msbpn__ftp=ireland&msbpn__ftp_x=1&msady=1924&msady_x=1&cpxt=0&uidh=pqh&msbdp=1&msadp=1&cp=0#) on Ancestry.com that is a possible match. I cannot access it because I don't have access to Canadian records. I retrieved the record by searching on Richard Richardson, born 1896-1898, arriving 1923-1925. The hit is for "Canada, Ocean Arrivals (Form 30A), 1919-1924." Perhaps someone else can validate whether that match is plausible or not for your Richard Richardson.

I think the reason this family arrived by ship on the East Coast of North America, rather than directly to San Francisco, is that by the 1920s, it was much faster to cross the continent by train that to take a ship through the Panama Canal.

Comment: The Canadian Ocean Arrivals form doesn't have a huge amount of detail to confirm or deny things - it says he is a Farm Labourer and intends to remain in Canada and gives Toronto as his destination. His wife is named as May (possibly Mary) with an address of "Aglish Coachford, Cork" or something like that - it's hard to read.

Comment: Hello Gene, Thank you for that....indeed it is Aglish, Coachford, Co Cork.... just a couple of miles from me.I have ancestry for UK & Ireland but I'll upgrade to worldwide next month. What is interesting is that in the 1940 US census living next door is a Michael Carroll which is Mary's maiden name. It's possible that's a coincidence though it does give me something to look into in the future. Many thanks.